# Swift collection view data being changed when scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, alignment

My collection view cells are being modified when scrolling all the way to the bottom and then back up.

In my viewDidLoad I have a Parse query which fetches all the values from the database and then calls reloadData from the main thread.

On the initial load the viewable cells are correctly displayed.

But when I scroll down the cells that were not visible are loaded and 1/3 of them are displayed incorrectly.

Then when I scroll back up to the initial viewable cells the first one is not displayed properly.

By not displayed properly I mean in my database is a field for alignment.  This can hold center, left, or right Strings.

This value is how my image and buttons should be aligned in the cell.

Here is my cellForRow function.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell{
    let cell: FeedThumbnail = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("feed_cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FeedThumbnail

    //handle cell alignment
    if(align[indexPath.row] == "left"){
        //leave alignment as is for buttons
        if(cell.picture.frame.origin.x == 0){
            cell.picture.frame.offsetInPlace(dx: -75, dy: 0)
        }
    }

    else if(align[indexPath.row] == "center"){
        cell.holder_view.frame.offsetInPlace(dx: 105 - cell.holder_view.frame.origin.x, dy: 0)
        //leave image as is
    }

    else if(align[indexPath.row] == "right"){
        cell.holder_view.frame.offsetInPlace(dx: 220 - cell.holder_view.frame.origin.x, dy: 0)
        cell.picture.frame.offsetInPlace(dx: 100 - cell.picture.frame.origin.x, dy: 0)
    }

    return cell
}
```

Here is the class for my collection view cell

```
 import UIKit

class FeedThumbnail: UICollectionViewCell {

 @IBOutlet weak var picture: UIImageView!
 @IBOutlet weak var comment_btn: UIButton!
 @IBOutlet weak var heart_btn: UIButton!
 @IBOutlet weak var rescip_btn: UIButton!
 @IBOutlet weak var og_btn: UIButton!
 @IBOutlet weak var name_lbl: UIButton!
 @IBOutlet weak var holder_view: UIView!
}
```

Comment: Can you post your `FeedThumbnail` class?

Comment: The buttons are all inside  of the holder_view

Comment: My guess is that your cell reuse is not working properly. Try overriding `prepareForReuse` in your `FeedThumbnail` class and reset all of your frames back to default.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by reset all frames back to default ?

Comment: Basically set them back to what they were when the cell first loads before you modify the frames. Since the cells get reused randomly, a cell that was center may be reused as a cell that is right. When it does this, it's frame is in the center position so your calculations may be off if you are expecting it to be in a different position.

Comment: So set the origin of the image view and view that are inside of the FeedThumbnail to origin.x = 0 pretty much?

Comment: Yea try that and see if it fixes your issue.

Comment: Glad I could help.

Comment: Ugh but now I'm having the issue where the first three cells are not properly aligned on initial load. They need to be scrolled to get loaded properly. This just started occurring once I had more then 12 cells.

Answer (score 1):

Like Lumialxk and RPK said.
I needed to refresh the cell origin.x before modifying it.

I guess I didn't understand that cells would be reused in the way that they were.

The solution was to override prepareForReuse and set the frame.origin.x back to the original value before modifying it.

import UIKit

class FeedThumbnail: UICollectionViewCell {

```
@IBOutlet weak var picture: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var comment_btn: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var heart_btn: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var rescip_btn: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var og_btn: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var name_lbl: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var holder_view: UIView!


override func prepareForReuse() {
    picture.frame.origin.x = 0
    holder_view.frame.origin.x = 0
    super.prepareForReuse()
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You got a condition in `cellFor...`, like this:

```
if(cell.picture.frame.origin.x == 0){...
```

If a cell was reused, it's `"left"` but not satisfied your condition so it'll keep its looks that was the same as that before reused. You should do something with this. Here is sample code:

```
if(cell.picture.frame.origin.x == 0){
    ...
} else {
    // make it a left cell
}
```

Comment: I'm not exactly following :/.   So basically I should switch my code around to do the adjustment in the else statement instead of the if statement? Wouldn't that modify the content alignment every time the cell comes into view?

Comment: @TomGreco Sorry for my bad expression. When you got a reused cell, it maybe left,right or center. You should refresh it otherwise you'll get a cell with original looks. Do you understand?